# Gráfico de linha personalizado

Tags: c#, desempenho, gráfico, drawing

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um programa em c# que deve desenhar um gráfico de linha(x,y) em uma picturebox(pcbANALISE) de acordo com os dados que eu tenho em uma lista (aquisicaodata[ ]). Este gráfico também conta com uma barra de rolagem para navegação pelo gráfico. Para desenhar estou utilizando o seguinte código.

```
    int camera;
    List<float> aquisicaodata = new List<float>();
    Graphics g;

    public void DrawANALISE()
    {
        g = pcbANALISE.CreateGraphics();
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        var lastPoint1 = new PointF(0F, (float)(2 * pcbANALISE.Height / 5) * 0.5F); //ultimo ponto
        PointF newPoint1 = new PointF(); //novo ponto

        for(int i = camera; i < pcbANALISE.Width/0.2f + camera; i++)
        {
            float porcent;
            if (i < 6000) porcent = aquisicaodata[i] / 5;
            else porcent = 0.5f;
            newPoint1.X = (i-camera+1) * 1f;
            newPoint1.Y = porcent * pcbANALISE.Height;
            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) g.DrawLine(p, lastPoint1, newPoint1);
            lastPoint1 = newPoint1;
        }
    }
```

Código do evento scroll da barra de rolagem horizontal:

```
    private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        camera = hScrollBar1.Value * 6000 / 100; // variavel usada para rolagem do grafico
        g.Clear(Color.FromArgb(65,65,65));
        DrawANALISE();
    }
```

Meu problema é o seguinte: Quando eu rolo a scroll, ao invés do gráfico se movimentar pra esquerda ou direita, ele é redesenhado desde o início a cada tick novo de rolagem. O que é muito lento, além de não ser da maneira pretendida. Alguém pode me ajudar com esse problema?? Muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Já experimentou colocar `pcbANALISE.SuspendLayout()` no início do método `DrawANALISE` e depois `pcbANALISE.ResumeLayout()` no fim?

Comment: Eu tive que colocar um metodo de atualização no evento scroll, porém o método Refresh() e o método Invalidate() estão fazendo cintilar muito, o que não me permite visualizar perfeitamente se melhorou ou não com o ajuste que você recomendou.

Comment: se eu nao coloco o metodo de atualização o grafico é sobreposto toda vez que o evento scroll é chamado.